# How to change permission in 11.04 version of ubuntu for root in the file system

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

Recently installed 11.04 version of ubuntu. Wanted to create a folder in the root of the fileSystem, but the persmission was denied. Tried with chown and chmod but no result.

Kindly assist me

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sudo mkdir /yourdir`

sudo means, that you will execute this command with root privileges

or use `sudo chmod` ... same princip

Comment: Thank you, can the same be achieved with mouse clicks... of creating folders and copy, paste operations... because this is denied in the right click of the content.

Comment: yes, you have at least 2 options.fisrt, that you can run nautilus (default file manager in ubuntu) as root by executing command: 'sudo nautilus', or you can activate root user and then login as root and do whatever you want. you need to do following: "sudo passwd root" and twice retype root's password, logout, and finally login as root.